# Failure saving State (Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi could anyone tell what I am missing in my code,
I got a Actionbar Tab, I inflate the content every-time the tab is triggered below is my process

-> click tab 

-> inflate the layout(fragment with dummy view) 

-> replace the dummy view with my real content (no addbackstack)

-> click another tab

-> put the app to background

then I got this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active Programsfragment{43ae6308 id=0x7f090042} has cleared index: -1
```

.

on tab

```
Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
        tabC.setText("Programs");
        tabC.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "Programs",
                ProgramsFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabC);
```

on programFragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();


            if (view != null) {

                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                if (parent != null) {System.out.println("sad");
                    parent.removeView(view);
                } else {
                    ft.detach(pFragment);
                    ft.attach(pFragment);
//refresh!
                    ft.replace(R.id.list, pFragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            } else {

                try {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, container, false);

                    ft.replace(R.id.list, pFragment);
                    //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                } catch (InflateException e) {

                }
            }
```

onpause the application crash with this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active Programsfragment{43ae6308 id=0x7f090042} has cleared index: -1
```

any suggestion or comments is well appreciated..thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it always crash or does it work the first time. It is perhaps that you are instantiating a new fragment each time but you never remove them. Can you also post the code that you described at the beginning of your post (click, inflate, etc)

Comment: @HpTerm it work the first time. I post the tab listener.

Comment: Which version of Android do you compile for ? Do you use support library ?

Comment: Do you have override 'onActivityCreated' in your fragement ?

Comment: @HpTerm sorry im new to this.. i think its nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar what do you mean on overiding onActivityCreated

Comment: It seems to me you are not doing the things the correct way. You only need to assign the tabs once for all in the 'Activity'. As it works the first time, to me you do not need to re-create the view each time the way you are doing. Let me show you some code.

Comment: @HpTerm that would be a great help thanks!